# NodeJS Mongoose can connect from one linux directory but not another

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Several months ago, I set up a production NodeJS app that uses `mongoose` to connect to a MongoDB database with the following connection string:

```
mongodb://@127.0.0.1:27017/invoice_app?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

I did not need to supply a username or password and everything worked.

I wanted to make a copy of the NodeJS project on the same server and point it to the same database.  I'll call this the `staging` NodeJS project. However, everytime I try to `npm start` my `staging` project, I get the error `(node:11495) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoParseError: No username provided in authority section`.

As far as I can tell, this `staging` project is the exact same as the production one.  Line by line, they should be the same, except they are in different directories. I reused the exact same connection string.  The NodeJS project is used owned/executed by the same user.

Why can mongoose connect from one directory but not another?  Is there something else I completely misunderstood?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I had deleted the `node_modules` directory from my staging project along the way. And when I ran the `npm install` in the staging directory, it didn't actually give me the correct `node_modules` package versions as production.  Here was the relevant lines from `package-lock.json` that resolved my issues in staging:

```
"mongodb": {
  "version": "3.3.5",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/mongodb/-/mongodb-3.3.5.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha1-ONUxATr+3pKw3SguO588CMm9/zs=",
  "requires": {
    "bson": "^1.1.1",
    "require_optional": "^1.0.1",
    "safe-buffer": "^5.1.2",
    "saslprep": "^1.0.0"
  }
},
"mongoose": {
  "version": "5.7.13",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/mongoose/-/mongoose-5.7.13.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha1-2Ou8Fc+xnQFM8fvUt69BPXWVLUY=",
  "requires": {
    "bson": "~1.1.1",
    "kareem": "2.3.1",
    "mongodb": "3.3.5",
    "mongoose-legacy-pluralize": "1.0.2",
    "mpath": "0.6.0",
    "mquery": "3.2.2",
    "ms": "2.1.2",
    "regexp-clone": "1.0.0",
    "safe-buffer": "5.1.2",
    "sift": "7.0.1",
    "sliced": "1.0.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "ms": {
      "version": "2.1.2",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/ms/-/ms-2.1.2.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha1-0J0fNXtEP0kzgqjrPM0YOHKuYAk="
    }
  }
},
"mongoose-legacy-pluralize": {
  "version": "1.0.2",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/mongoose-legacy-pluralize/-/mongoose-legacy-pluralize-1.0.2.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha1-O6n5H6UHtRhtOZ+0CFS/8Y+1Y+Q="
},
```